# jScript debugger error, in simple script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstorage

I'm working on a local html file, stored on a Win7 machine and opened in IE 9. This html file uses javascript and jStorage.

However, when I run, I get the error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'set': object is null or undefined." This error points to the statement `$.jStorage.set("Key", "Hello");`.

What am I doing wrong? I've made the html and javascript about as basic as I can, to narrow things down.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Backlog Tracker</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="json2.js"></script>
    <script src="jstorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="backlog.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and, here's the script (referenced as "backlog.js" in the html):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append("<button>Try It</button>");
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.jStorage.set("Key", "Hello");
    console.log($.jStorage.get("Key"));
    });
});
```

As a side note, I've read other questions on SO, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2972640/2658159), but nothing seems to explain this. Reference jStorage usage [here](http://www.jstorage.info/#usage), everything seems to be in order. I was originally pointed to jStorage thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163135/2658159).

Comment: Are you accessing this HTML file simply as a file, or is it part of a local server system (ie, localhost:80/page.html)? localStorage values must be associated with a hostname, and I doubt the browser can treat "file://" as a hostname.

Comment: It's accessed simply as a file. localStorage will not work, but based on one of the links above(http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163135/2658159) I was hoping jStorage would be a work-around.

Comment: The error message suggests `$.jStorage` is not defined - if you do `console.log($.jStorage)` what do you get? I assume there are no loading errors earlier in the log?

Comment: @CupawnTae: no loading errors earlier in the log. If I insert `console.log($.jStorage)` before `$.jStorage.set("Key", "Hello");`, I get "LOG: undefined"

Comment: Ok, so the problem is definitely that jStorage isn't loaded correctly. It's possible that @Mooseman's answer explains the reason for this so I'd suggest you make the updates he proposes and see if it helps.

Comment: Could you try this please?: http://jsfiddle.net/5hjj8/1/
It's working here.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage does not work for local files in IE. It does in Chrome but not in IE.

Also IE 9 does support JSON if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />` in your document.

Try to run a small local web server.

Comment: Does this explain the behaviour? jStorage is supposed to provide fallbacks, and "If the browser doesn't support data caching, then no exceptions are raised - jStorage can still be used by the script but nothing is actually stored." (http://www.jstorage.info/).

Comment: Could you please check if `$.jStorage.storageAvailable()` and what the `$.jStorage.currentBackend()` is?

Comment: Have you tried using `jquery.json-2.3.min.js` instead of `json2.js`, see http://www.jjask.com/300384/jquery-jstorage-issue-on-ie8?

Comment: `$.jStorage` is undefined - see the comments on the question. So `$.jStorage.storageAvailable()` will just throw an error

Comment: Does it work with the [suggested](http://www.jstorage.info/#usage) include code? It could be a version problem. Also you might want to switch to the newer version [simpleStorage](https://github.com/andris9/simpleStorage) if you do not need IE7.

Comment: @PiTheNumber sorry, adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" /> doesn't change this. Still getting same error in the same place.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: attempted to check $.jStorage.storageAvailable(), but got error "Unable to get value of the property 'storageAvailable': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @AaronThomas Does it work with the [suggested](http://www.jstorage.info/#usage) include code? It could be a version problem. Also you might want to switch to the newer version [simpleStorage](https://github.com/andris9/simpleStorage) if you do not need IE7.